# How to check a string for keywords as it is being updated by a keylogger?

Tags: python, string, keylogger

So I have a pretty simple keylogger which throws the keys into a string. I'd like to be able to check for words as that string is updated with keys. For example I would have a preset list such as

```
matches = 'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas' etc
```

What I was thinking was something like

```
if any(matches in str(keys)
print("true")
```

that does not work though, and I cannot find another question relating specifically to my circumstances.
I know that I could just go the "if elif" route such as

```
if "banana" in str(keys)
print("True")
elif "oranges" in str(keys)
print ("True")
```

but that is far to bulky, and I ran into a recursion error when I had hundreds of words like that. Therefore, I'd like to have one massive "bank" of words to run as the string is updated with keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

Save the keylogger output to a string.

The String should be always in the length of the longest word in ***matches*** array since there's not chance of a word with more characters.

After that you can use this approach:

```
from  builtins import any
if any(match in keylogger_string for match in matches):
        print("True")
```

If you are using python version 2.x you should change `builtins` to `__builtin__`

Comment: that works but it prints true if any LETTER is typed, for example if I type in apples, it prints "true" as soon as I press "A". Would I be able to only make it search for whole words?

Comment: just start checking it once your string is in the length of the longest word